# Show node links in modal buttonpane

Tags: 8, nodes, ajax, modal-dialogs

I want to show some node fields in buttonpane when I open node in modal.

As far as I know, it will automatically show there inputs with type submit and links with class button, but I added class button on email field link, anchor rendered is like:

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com" class="button">Send email</a>
```

but it's not showing in buttonpane.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I just figured out from *[core/misc/dialog/dialog.ajax.js](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.9.x/core/misc/dialog/dialog.ajax.js#L39)* that I need wrapper with class form-actions.

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <a href="mailto:test@example.com" class="button">Send email</a>
</div>
```